# Prestashop apply coupon code automatically

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I need to apply 10% discount on order total on checkout page.

Is there any option available to apply discount coupon automatically on checkout page with help of overriding controller or ajax based or any other method?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to override the classes or edit the code to apply the automatic coupon on any cart.

In order to achieve this, you can add a 'Catalog Price Rules' from the admin panel of your store to apply 10% discount on all products in the cart or specific country or specific currency etc.

Admin Path:

Price Rules -> Catalog Price Rules

Answer (score 0):

go to price rules->cart rule->add

> in conditions enter the minimum amount
>
> in actions apply discount % and Apply a discount to order

(prestashop 1.6)

Ok an other way (quick and dirty) :

> edit Cart.php in classes and modify the return of getOrderTotal
>
> return Tools::ps_round((float)$order_total * my_discount,
>   $compute_precision);

Override method :

```
class Cart extends CartCore 
{
    public function getOrderTotal($with_taxes = true, $type = Cart::BOTH, $products = null, $id_carrier = null, $use_cache = true)
    {
    return parent::getOrderTotal(true, Cart::ONLY_PRODUCTS) * mydiscount;

    }

}
```

Comment: No, I want any custom method via programming.